# Random draw and fraction of each class is arbitrary

Tags: sampling, stratification

I am working on a dataset with binary outcome variable $\{0,1\}$. The data provider said samples are drawn randomly from the population while the sample proportion of outcome $0$ is arbitrarily set. That means the sample proportion of outcome $1$ is also arbitrarily set. Furthermore, the population proportions are different from the sample proportions.

I am assuming that the data are drawn using stratified sampling method where stratum is the outcome.

Can I assume it this way? Or could it mean something else.

Comment: Your description is not very clear. Are you saying that the proportions in the {0, 1} classes differ between your sample and the population? What is the question?

Comment: @Tim Yes? I am saying that the proportions in the $\{0,1\}$ are different between sample and the population. And the sample proportions are arbitrarily set by the data provider. My question is if I can assume stratified sampling method.

Comment: Well, either they used or they didn’t use stratified sampling, there’s not much to assume in here.

Comment: @Tim can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Stratified sampling is a method of sampling. Same as if you get warm food you don’t assume it was fried, since there are multiple ways of warming food other then frying, you cannot deduce from the data itself how it was collected.

Comment: The are so many ways to "randomly" draw samples from any population that you can never assume you know how it was done: you need to inquire of your data provider.  (Even then, many providers don't truly randomize or do it improperly: unless you are confident of their statistical knowledge, you have to investigate their procedures thoroughly.)

Comment: @Tim, whuber how about assuming that samples are random within each class? As I know that samples are drawn randomly from the population.

Comment: You know that they were sampled randomly or you assume it? Moreover you need to know what “random” means.

Comment: I’m closing this question. You seem not to know where did your data come from. This is not something that can be guessed or assumed and we can help you with it. Just ask the data provider how exactly did they collect the data so you can judge if the methodology was sound.

Comment: @Tim I know that they were sampled randomly. But I am confused because "drawn randomly from the population" and "the sample proportion of outcome 0 is arbitrarily set" are contradicting. I want to know that if I can deduce that the data are random given the outcome from these two sentences.

Comment: You need to know the methodology they used, not make a guess based on two sentences.

Comment: This is a bit of a guess, but "proportion ... arbitrarily set" suggests to me the sampling was stratified on the outcome variable.  One would hope each stratum was randomly sampled (likely with replacement), but you really do have to consult the data provider (or their documentation) for the details.