# random sampling while arbitrarily set the proportion of outcome

Tags: sampling

This question is related to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/532089/random-draw-and-fraction-of-each-class-is-arbitrary?noredirect=1#comment977353_532089), but I am asking a different question.

I am working on a dataset with binary outcome variable {0,1}. The data provider said samples are drawn randomly from the population while the sample proportion of outcome 0 is arbitrarily set. That means the sample proportion of outcome 1 is also arbitrarily set. Furthermore, the population proportions are different from the sample proportions.

Can I say "given an outcome, the data are random"? I cannot contact the data provider for more details as it was publicly available data.

Comment: (1) The phrase "data are random" is essentially meaningless.  As pointed out in comments to your previous question, the details of the sampling method need to be known. (2) Publicly available data of any quality will be accompanied by metadata which document the data source(s), the processing applied, and provide some indications of data quality. If such metadata are unavailable, consider the data unreliable for any purpose apart from education and illustration of techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the model, the randomness of a sample can be difficult to verify. In the case where the data consist
only of $0$'s and $1$'s, one might look at the lengths of runs.

For example, if $0$'s and $1$'s are equally likely,
then runs of $0$'s ought to be of average length $2$ and the same for runs of $1$'s. In particular, in a random sequence of twenty $0$'s and $1$'s where the two outcomes are equally likely, we would not be surprised to to see:

```
0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0
```

while we would be surprised to see runs of length five and six as in

```
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
```

But you say you don't have access to original data.
For instances in which you do have original data, you might want to look at pages on this site and online
that discuss 'runs tests' for randomness.

**Testing proprotions.** In your case, it seems you don't have access to the original data, but a summary of how many $1$'s and how many $0$'s were
observed.
Then it is not possible to test for randomness, but it is easy to check
whether a particular proportion of $1$'s seen in a sample
of size $n$ is likely to have resulted, sampling from
a population with a particular probability of $1$'s.

It would be unusual for the sample proportion to be exactly equal to the population probability, but the two numbers should not be extremely different.

*Example:* Suppose the population probability of ones is
$p = 0.4$ and we observe $X = 387$ ones in a sample of
size $n$ from the population, so that the sample estimate
of $p$ is $\hat p = x/n = 387/1000 = 0.387.$

We could formulate the null hypothesis $H_0: p = 0.4$ and the alternative $H_a: p \ne 0.4.$ Then under the null hypothesis $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=1000, p=0.4).$ We
could use an exact binomial test in R to test $H_0$ against $H_a$ at the 5% level of significance.

```
binom.test(x=387, n=1000, p=0.4)

        Exact binomial test

data:  387 and 1000
number of successes = 387, number of trials = 1000, 
 p-value = 0.4198

alternative hypothesis: 
 true probability of success is not equal to 0.4
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.3566826 0.4179848
sample estimates:
probability of success 
                 0.387
```

If $H_0$ is true, then the P-value $0.4198$ is the
probability of a more extreme outcome than the observed
$X = 387.$  In R, where `pbinom` is a binomial CDF, this can be computed directly, as follows.

```
S = pbinom(387, 1000, 0.4); S
[1] 0.210093        # P(X <= 287)
L = 1 - pbinom(412, 1000, 0.4);  L
[1] 0.2096599       # P(X >= 413)
S + L
[1] 0.4197529       # P(More extreme)
```

Because the P-value $0.4198 > 0.05 = 5\%,$ we do not
reject $H_0$ at the 5% level of significance. That is,
the observed value $X = 387$ is not surprisingly
different from the 'expected' value $400.$

The figure below shows the PDF of the null distribution $\mathsf{Binom}(n=1000, p=0.5).$ Total heights of bars
outside the red vertical lines represent the P-value of the test.

[image]

R code for figure above.

```
hdr = "PDF of BINOM(1000, 0.4)"
x = 350:450;  PDF = dbinom(x, 1000, .4)
plot(x, PDF, type="h", col="blue", lwd=2, main=hdr)
 abline(h = 0, col="green2")
 abline(v = 387.5, col="red")
 abline(v = 412.5, col="red", lty="dashed")
```

By contrast, if we happened to observe $X = 435$ or $X = 362,$ these values would lead to P-values below 5%,
and we would reject $H_0: p = 0.4.$ Here are the exact
P-values that would result from these outcomes according
to `binom.test`. [We use `$`-notation to show just the
two P-values, instead of the complete output as above.]

```
binom.test(x=435, n=1000, .4)$p.val
[1] 0.02589798
binom.test(x=362, n=1000, .4)$p.val
[1] 0.01416038
```

Comment: There is no assurance the sequence of records in a dataset is the sequence in which it was obtained.  Thus, the relevance of runs of zeros and ones looks tenuous at best and could be highly misleading.

Comment: @whuber. Right. I mentioned runs only for original data. As in my Answer: "In your case, it seems you don't have access to the original data, but a summary of how many 1's and how many 0's were observed.... Then it is not possible to test for randomness...." followed by binomial tests.

Comment: Okay--but why discuss an irrelevant point, then?

Comment: Because I wondered whether OP might be interested primarily in randomness: "Can I say 'given an outcome, the data are random'?" If _outcome_ means just a tally of 0s and 1s, then No. // Adjusting answer slightly (with some redundancy) to be sure this is clear.